# How to draw a table with data from Mysql?

Tags: php

I have obtained the following data through Mysql.

```
idx item_name parent_id
44   'A'         -1
46   'B'         -1
47   'C'         44
48   'D'         44
49   'E'         44
50   'F'         46
51   'G'         47
52   'H'         47
53   'I'         48
```

I want to draw a table using this data.
I've searched for information, but it's very difficult.
Is there anyone who can help me?

***Example***

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>item1</th>
            <th>item2</th>
            <th>item3</th>
            <th>value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2">C</td>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>I</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>-</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is there a PHP library related to this?

=========================================

The values in the database consist of a passenger structure. (Parent ID Existence)

I want to make this data into a table using PHP.
"Rowspan" will be used to accommodate the number of children.
However, this method of HTML coding is very difficult.

I need a library or a related example code.

Comment: add more details to your questions

Comment: @Jerson I added the Question.

Comment: @코어랩 Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problem/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, the code that I made to solve your problem.
It is not perfect but I hope you got the idea.
Your problem cannot be solved by a simple array loop, because your data is not a simple table but a tree. Therefore, using recursive loop to walk through the data is one of the solutions.

```
<?php    

// the data, should be obtained from your database
// to simplify the code, I made them into an array of objects
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 44, 'name' => 'A', 'pid' => -1 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 46, 'name' => 'B', 'pid' => -1 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 47, 'name' => 'C', 'pid' => 44 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 48, 'name' => 'D', 'pid' => 44 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 49, 'name' => 'E', 'pid' => 44 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 50, 'name' => 'F', 'pid' => 46 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 51, 'name' => 'G', 'pid' => 47 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 52, 'name' => 'H', 'pid' => 47 );
$rows[] = (object) array( 'idx' => 53, 'name' => 'I', 'pid' => 48 );

// Build Tree
foreach($rows as $r) {
    $r->child = [];
    foreach($rows as $c) {
        if($r->idx == $c->idx) continue;
        if($c->pid == $r->idx)
            $r->child[] = $c;
    }
}

// recursive walk through the trees to set maxLevel and nodeLevel
function cLeaves($node, $level, &$maxLevel) {
    $count = 0;
    if(count($node->child) == 0) {
        $node->span = 1;
        $node->level = $level;
        $maxLevel = $maxLevel < $level ? $level : $maxLevel;
        return 1;
    } else {
        $node->level = $level;
        $level++;
        foreach($node->child as $c) {
            $count += cLeaves($c, $level, $maxLevel);
        }
        $node->span = $count;
        return $count;
    }    
}

// recursive walk through the trees to draw table
function drawTable($cnode, $maxLevel) {
    echo '<td rowspan="'.$cnode->span.'">'.$cnode->name.'</td>';
    if(count($cnode->child) == 0) {
        if($cnode->level < $maxLevel) {
            for($i = $cnode->level; $i<$maxLevel; $i++) 
                echo '<td>-</td>';    
        }
        echo '<td>-</td>'; // for the value column
        echo '</tr>';
        return;
    }
    foreach($cnode->child as $c) {
        drawTable($c, $maxLevel);
    }
}

// update the data structure
$maxLevel = 0;
foreach($rows as $r) {
    if($r->pid == -1) {
        $level = 0;
        $r->span = cLeaves($r, $level, $maxLevel);
        $r->level = $level;
    }
}

echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
// draw table's title row
for($i = 0; $i <= $maxLevel; $i++) {
    echo '<td>item'.($i+1).'</td>';
    if($i == $maxLevel) echo '<td>value</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// draw tree on table format
foreach($rows as $r) {
    if($r->pid == -1) {
        echo '<tr>';
        drawTable($r, $maxLevel);
    }
}
echo '</table>';
    
?>
```

If you run the code, the result would be something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What I still remember from PHP is, you can use `for loop` and put one of these rows into the php `<tag>`. Then use your `SELECT` query to `get` each tuple from **MySql** into each tuple's cells in this tag:

```
<tr> 
    <td> Cell value using Sql Select statement</td>
    <td> Cell value using Sql Select statement</td>
    <td> Cell value using Sql Select statement</td>
</tr>
```

You can do this process `n` of times depend on the *No. Of rows* you want to insert into the table.

Then, close your **PHP `<tag>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysqli_fetch_assoc to fetch your data from the database and run a loop to format it using html table:

```
<table border=1>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>idx</th>
        <th>item_name</th>
        <th>parent_id</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yourdatabase");
    $table = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT idx, item_name, parent_id FROM mytable");

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($table)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $record["idx"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record["item_name"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record["parent_id"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    ?>
</tbody>
```

If you want to use a library, you can check codeigniter (PHP framework)'s table helper.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/table.html

```
$this->table->generate($table);
```